# file_get_contents with header: Send current header or current cookie in magento or common

Tags: php, magento, cookies, http-headers, file-get-contents

I want to call an URL and want to get the result with PHP by using `file_get_contents` (I know CURL, but first I want to try it with `file_get_contents`). In my case it's a request to the `magento` shop system, which requires a previously done login to the backend.

If I execute the URL manually in my browser, the right page is coming. If I send the URL with `file_get_contents`, I will also get logged in (because I added the Cookie to the request), but everytime I get only the dashboard home site, maybe something causes a redirect.

I tried to simulate the same http request, as my browser send it away. My question is: Is there a possiblity to send the same header data (Cookie, Session-ID etc.) directly as parameter to `file_get_contents` without manual serialization?

It's a common PHP question, the basic script would be:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

And in my case the code is:

```
        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array
            (
                'selected_products' => 'some content',
            )
        );

        $opts = array('http' =>
            array
            (
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n".
                             "Cookie: __utma=".Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get("__utma").";".
                             "__utmz=".Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get("__utmz").
                             " __utmc=".Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get("__utmc").';'.
                             "adminhtml=".Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get("adminhtml")."\r\n".
                             "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n".
                             "Connection: keep-alive\r\n".
                             "Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*\r\n".
                             "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0",
                'content' => $postdata
            )
        );

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
var_dump(file_get_contents($runStopAndRemoveProducts, false, $context ));
```

The result should be the same error message I'll get in the browser by calling the URL manually ("please select some products" as plain text), but the response is a full dashboard home page as html website.

I'm looking for a script like this. I want to make sure all parameters are set automatically without manual build the cookie string and the other ones :)

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $_SESSION["Current_Header"]);
```

**EDIT:** I've found the mistake, two special get-Parameter (`isAjax=1` and `form_key` = `Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'))->getFormKey()`) are required. In my case the `form_key` causes the error. But the ugly Cookie string is already there - still looking for a more pretty solution.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you are trying to write a hack for something that you can do more elegantly, the proper, fully documented way. Please have a look at the Magento API.

If you want to delete products (or do anything else):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.delete.html

You will get a proper response back to know if things have been successful. If there are things the API cannot do then you can extend/hack it if you wish.

To get started you will need an API user/pass and get up to speed with SOAP. The examples in the Magento documentation should suffice. Good luck!

Comment: In general you're right :-) In this case we're using the "M2E Pro" Extension for creating eBay/Amazon-Listings/Products from a ERP-software. So we have to call the M2E-Pro functions which unfortuantely aren't available with SOAP or similiar things.